# HTML setting background-image PATH

Tags: html, css, image

I'm having some problems because I can't set my background photo from CSS file.

I'm using netbeans. I have a folder called css and inside I have the global.css. Inside global.css i have this code:

```
body{
    background-image: url(/images/background.jpg);
}
```

Background.jpg is inside a folder called images, the structure is the following:

```
--Web Pages
     -css
         global.css
     -images
         background.jpg

     -index.html
--Source Packages
--etc
```

It is not working, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is inside the css(global.css) it should go one level up (css folder, images folder) and then go inside the images folder.

```
body{
    background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem.

Comment: @user2911701 You are welcome. [This is useful article for css paths](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/) and [this one](http://jeffreybarke.net/2013/06/paths-and-urls-relative-and-absolute/)

Answer (score 2):

Is the css loading correctly? If so, then take a look to the url: using **trailing hash** before images/ links to the root of your server, but your image it's not there. Use `../` to go upper in your filesistem and **then** enter into your *images* folder. This should work:

```css
body{
    background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the path to this: `background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);`